Generar Reporte CSV
Cuando genero un reporte desde un "Assertion Results" y el jmeter me pide sobreescribir el archivo csv (vacio) y lo acepto. Al abrirlo la informacion se muestra contenida en una sola celda y no distribuida ordenadamente como deberia ser (Ayuda por favor).


Abres un excel en blanco -> Datos -> De texto /CSV https://i.sstatic.net/3FCVrdlD.png
